# Solving integral using Laplace transform

Tags: calculus, integration, laplace-transform, trigonometric-integrals

My goal is to find the integral below using Laplace transform, which is supposed to simplify it. However, I am stuck and don't know how to write the full solution.
$$I=\int_{0}^{x} (x - y)^2 \cos(3y)  dy$$
Here's my attempt at some ideas:

I've been suggested to rewrite $(x-y)^2$ as $y^2$ (due to convulation?) and proceed to do Laplace transform. According to the formula table I get $\mathcal{L}\{y^2\}=\frac{2}{s^{3}}$. Similarly, $\mathcal{L}\{\cos(3y)\}=\frac{s}{s^{2}+9}$. Could someone please help me arrive at the full solution?

Comment: Write $\int_0^x (x-y)^2\cos(3y)\;\mathrm dy=\int_0^x f(x-y)g(y)\;\mathrm dy$. What do you know about the Laplace transform of a convolution?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I know the definition $(f* g)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}f(t-\tau)g(\tau)d\tau=\int_{0}^{t}f(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau$, but I don't see how to proceed further. Similarly, after computing the Laplace transform of the integral, how exactly do we get to the final solution of the integral itself?

Comment: And $\mathcal L(f*g)=\mathcal L(f)\cdot\mathcal L(g)$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Thank you for the reply. So I should just take the product of individual Laplace transforms of $(x-y)^2$ and $\cos(3y)$, then? After that I still don't see how to arrive at the integral result.

Comment: Not $(x-y)^2$ but $y^2$ ($x-y$ comes from the convolution, the functions are $f(y)=y^2$ and $g(y)=\cos(3y)$). The Laplace transforms are resp. $\dfrac{2}{s^3}$ and $\dfrac{s}{s^2+9}$, you already found that. The product is thus $\dfrac{2}{s^2(s^2+9)}$, and it's the Laplace transform of $I$. Now you want to find the inverse Laplace transform of this. The usual way: find the partial fraction decomposition: it's $\dfrac{2/9}{s^2}-\dfrac{2/9}{s^2+9}$. Are you able to finish from this?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I appreciate your help, I have managed to calculate the inverse and it is $\frac{2}{9}t-\frac{2}{27}\sin(3t)$. May I ask is this the final solution to the integral or do I need to do something more? I am confused because I see $t$ in the answer, and I am not really familiar with non-numerical solutions to integrals.

Comment: It's $x$ in the solution, not $t$, but apart from that it's correct. And this was to be expected, as there is an $x$ in the integrand as well as the bounds, so there is no reason to expect a purely numerical result.